# 500 Internal serve errorr in Azure

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-roles

We have recently upgraded our OS family from guest to family 2 with SDK version 1.8 to our .Net Application.

There is no code change and recently facing issue with 500 internal server error in our stage area. Once we reboot the Instances application working well again.

Any insight on how to flush the requests instead manually rebooting website and worker Instances.

Comment: You should probably **read the error message**.

Comment: I debugged it using the Firebug in Fire fox. Its showing only 500 Internal server error for particular CORS content. Other data types like .mpa and .jpeg are working fine.

Comment: Use Fiddler to see the whole response text and post it here. Also, add your interpretation.

Comment: </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>500 - Internal server error.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Disable custom errors so that you receive the full error. Or, remote debug the app and set the debugger to break on all exceptions.

Comment: could you please let me know how to remote debug the app..

Comment: @Yukesh57: It'd be much easier to just disable custom errors - you'll see the error message in Fiddler and/or browser.